# Error in laravel webmix run

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

```
E:\wamp64\www\project>npm run webpack
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: webpack
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\wamp64\www\project\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Please share what do you want to do exactly.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

it should be `npm run dev` check your package.json file the term you are using `webpack` needs to be in scripts section, laravel out of box supports `dev` and `prod` only.